# add columns different length pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with adding columns in pandas.
I have DataFrame, dimensional is nxk. And in process I wiil need add columns with dimensional mx1, where m = [1,n], but I don't know m.

When I try do it:

```
df['Name column'] = data    
# type(data) = list
```

result:

```
AssertionError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Can I add columns with different length?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use concat and pass `axis=1` and `ignore_index=True`:

```
In [38]:

import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.arange(4)})
print(df1)
df
   b
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
Out[38]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
In [39]:

pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
Out[39]:
   0   1
0  0   0
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  3   3
4  4 NaN
```

Comment: @TheRedPea I rolled your edit back, your suggestion should've been a comment rather than an edit of my answer as edits should be used to improve or correct an answer, not to suggest alternative answers

Comment: Definitively want to go down to "The Red Pea" answer, more precise.

Answer (score 110):

If you use accepted answer, you'll lose your column names, as shown in the accepted answer *example*, and described in the [*documentation*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) (emphasis added):

> The resulting axis will be labeled 0, ..., n - 1. This is useful if you are concatenating objects where the concatenation axis does **not** have meaningful indexing information.

It looks like column names (`'Name column'`) are meaningful to the Original Poster / Original Question.

To save column names, use `pandas.concat`, but **don't** `ignore_index` (default value of `ignore_index` is `False`; so you can omit that argument altogether). Continue to use `axis=1`:

```
import pandas

# Note these columns have 3 rows of values:
original = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Age':[10, 12, 13], 
    'Gender':['M','F','F']
})

# Note this column has 4 rows of values:
additional = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Nate A', 'Jessie A', 'Daniel H', 'John D']
})

new = pandas.concat([original, additional], axis=1) 
# Identical:
# new = pandas.concat([original, additional], ignore_index=False, axis=1) 

print(new.head())

#          Age        Gender        Name
#0          10             M      Nate A
#1          12             F    Jessie A
#2          13             F    Daniel H
#3         NaN           NaN      John D
```

Notice how John D does not have an Age or a Gender.

Comment: This answer was my choice, also, just a comment that if you are using your Pandas dataframe, in part to the write to a csv with pd.to_csv("filename") this will actually (by default) replace all the NAN with a blank anyway leaving a nice clean csv to import elsewhere....

Comment: If appears that if you change all the NaN to '' with df.fillna(''), python still thinks that all the columns are the original length.  How would you tell pandas that the columns now have different lengths?  This is a problem if you want to use the .sum() method on a column because you get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'.

Comment: @kozowh do you mean like in my example where the `Age` column is shorter than the  `Name` column and therefore `Age` has NaN values in the last row? Can you just sum the column directly without using `fillna('')`? Pandas aggregation functions will ignore NaN values: `df.Age.sum() == 35`

Comment: @kozowh, you could also `df.dropna().sum()` if you wanted to ignore all rows where **any**  column has an NaN or NaT values. I [show some approaches here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/theredpea/7f06d22ec3a275b66c2f5b6b6c4eb4d6/-add-columns-of-different-length.ipynb), all of my approaches **avoid `fillna('')`. But I don't know if I understand your question.

Comment: @NateAnderson Looks like `df.dropna.sum()` or `df.mean(axis=1)` will do the trick for me.

Answer (score 16):

**We can add the different size of list values to DataFrame.**

> Example

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
c = [0,1]
```

> Find the Length of all list

```
la,lb,lc = len(a),len(b),len(c)
# now find the max
max_len = max(la,lb,lc)
```

> Resize all according to the determined max length (not in this example

```
if not max_len == la:
  a.extend(['']*(max_len-la))
if not max_len == lb:
  b.extend(['']*(max_len-lb))
if not max_len == lc:
  c.extend(['']*(max_len-lc))
```

> Now the all list is same length and create dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b,'C':c})
```

> Final Output is

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  2  1   
2  3  2   
3     3   
4     4   
5     5   
6     6   
7     7   
8     8   
9     9
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, two different dataframes and without a common column. I just needed to put them beside each other in a csv file.

- Merge: 
  In this case, "merge" does not work; even adding a temporary column to both dfs and then dropping it. Because this method makes both dfs with the same length. Hence, it repeats the rows of the shorter dataframe to match the longer dataframe's length.
- Concat: 
  The idea of [The Red Pea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175496/the-red-pea) didn't work for me. It just appended the shorter df to the longer one (row-wise) while leaving an empty column (NaNs) above the shorter df's column.
- **Solution**: You need to do the following:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df = [df1, df2]
df_final = pd.concat(df, axis=1)

df_final.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

This way, you'll see your `dfs` besides each other (column-wise), each of which with its own length.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody like to replace a specific column of a different size instead of adding it.

Based on this answer, I use a dict as an intermediate type.
[Create Pandas Dataframe with different sized columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66947749/create-pandas-dataframe-with-different-sized-columns)

If the column to be inserted is not a list but already a dict, the respective line can be omitted.

```
def fill_column(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, list: list, column: str):
    dict_from_list = dict(enumerate(list)) # create enumertable object from list and create dict

    dataFrame_asDict = dataframe.to_dict() # Get DataFrame as Dict
    dataFrame_asDict[column] = dict_from_list # Assign specific column

    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataFrame_asDict, orient='index').T # Create new DataSheet from Dict and return it
```