# Combining a list as columns and a nested list with corresponding values as row values in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a list and a nested list with the following formats:

```
list_of_groups = [ 'group1', 'group2', ... , 'group59', 'group60'] # Made up of 60 elements
```

```
nested_hosts = [['hosta_grp1', 'hostb_grp1', 'hostc_grp1'], ['hosta_grp2', 'hostb_grp2'], ... ,['hosta_grp60', 'hostb_grp60', 'hostc_grp60]] # Made up of 60 nested lists all of different number of elements
```

I am trying to create a dataframe using pandas so that I can see the data above in the following way:

```
group1     group2   ......   group59       group60
hosta_grp1 hosta_grp2        hosta_grp59   hosta_grp60
hostb_grp1 hostb_grp2        hostb_grp59   hostb_grp60
hostc_grp1                   hostc_grp59   hostc_grp60
                             hostd_grp59
```

I've tried the above using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nested_hosts, columns = list_of_groups)
```

And I get this error:

```
60 columns passed, passed data had 2367 columns.
```

Comment: Perhaps something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404243/365102

Comment: Your columns are of different lengths, which isn't technically allowed in a typical dataframe.

Comment: it will work if you have an array of equal lengths, looks like have 2367 nested lists.

Comment: ok the above suggestion didnt work but i think its because of the nature of data frames and what I am trying to achieve. thank you