# Concatenate single row dataframe with multiple row dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe with large number of columns but single row as `df1`:

```
Col1 Col2   Price   Qty
A    B      16      5
```

I have another dataframe as follows, `df2`:

```
Price   Qty
8       2.5
16      5
6       1.5
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Price   Qty
A       B       8       2.5
A       B       16      5
A       B       6       1.5
```

Where essentially I am taking all rows of `df1` and repeat it while concatenating with `df2` but bring the `Price` and `Qty` columns from `df2` and replace the ones present originally in `df1`.

I am not sure how to proceed with above.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).ffill().drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: @abokey is right! When using `pd.concat` with `ignore_index=True`, the labels of the columns vanish, but you can restore them as I do in my solution to your previous question: In sum, to the new dataframe, you have to set the column names to `df.columns`.

Comment: This question seems to be similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126511/add-columns-different-length-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following approach will work,

```
# first lets repeat the single row df1 as many times as there are rows in df2
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df1.values, len(df2.index), axis=0), columns=df1.columns)

# lets reset the indexes of both DataFrames just to be safe
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

# now, lets merge the two DataFrames based on the index
# after dropping the Price and Qty columns from df1
df3 = pd.merge(df1.drop(['Price', 'Qty'], axis=1), df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# finally, lets drop the index columns
df3.drop(['index_x', 'index_y'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```